# Freeze gridview headers only on vertical scroll

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, scroll

I have a gridview which is wider than than my aspx page, so i need the headers of the gridview to scroll with the horizontal scroll bar but remain fixed with the vertical scroll bar, how do i acheive this? please help? after a lot of googling, i tried with various css classes after placing my grid inside a div pane, but that locks both the header both ways, horizontal and vertical. Please help me to fix headers only on vertical scroll.

part of my aspx page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
                                <div runat="server" id="GridViewDiv" style="overflow:auto" >
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="BindOnPostBack" Value="1" runat="server" /> 
                                    <asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="ProjectsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                        OnRowCreated="BudgetGridView_RowCreated"  OnRowDataBound="BudgetGridView_RowDataBound" PagerSettings-Visible="true" PageSize="20"
                                        AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" RowStyle-BackColor="#E8EAF7" RowStyle-BorderColor="White"
                                        RowStyle-Height="19px" RowStyle-Font-Size="11px" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" RowStyle-Font-Names="Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial"
                                        HeaderStyle-BackColor="#d1d5ef" HeaderStyle-Height="22px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="13px"
                                        HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="false" RowStyle-Wrap="false"
                                        PagerSettings-Position="Top" DataKeyNames="ID">


and my css for this:

div#GridViewDiv { 
width: expression(document.getElementById("ctl00_contentPanel").style.width); 
height: expression(document.getElementById("contentdiv").style.width);
overflow: scroll; 
position: relative; 
}

div#GridViewDiv th {   
top: expression(document.getElementById("GridViewDiv").scrollTop - 2); 
left: expression(parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollLeft); 
position: relative; 
z-index: 50;
} 

td.locked, th.locked {
position:relative;    
left:expression((this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollLeft-2)+'px');
}
```

Comment: can you show your html and css?

Comment: Thanks for stopping by bot. I have added the relevant code, any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The `position:fixed;` property will fix the component in place based on the browser.

Comment: but the div position has to be relative to the browser, if the size of the browser is reduced, it doesnt work fine if i keep the position fixed! also, it doesnt solve the basic problem, i need to freeze the header only on vertical scroll and keep it moving on horizontal scroll!

Comment: isn't there any standard way of doing it? i thought this was a very basic need of grid views!!! Please help.. im sure somebody would have implemented this!

Comment: @Viniez I never really used fixed position, so other than telling you it exists, I can't help further.